# SMACK LSM Module behaves strangely

Tags: linux, openssl, kernel

I want the following:

1. I want to use openssl to change the keys. So, I created the directory "***/etc/keys***" which I labelled "***keys***". I created a file "***key***" with same access "***keys***" and another key file "***forbiddenkey***" with access "***forbidden***" under the directory "***etc/keys***".
2. I made the openssl command execute as "***secure***".
3. I made the following rules
   secure keys rw
   secure forbidden -
4. I tested the rules as shown in the figure below and they seem to work.

[image: smack image]

5. But when I tried to actually run the command it didn't work even though the WRITE access is allowed to /etc/keys and /etc/keys/key

   **openssl rand 32 > /etc/keys/key**

The error message is as follows

```
-bash: /etc/keys/key: Permission denied
```

The audit message is as follows

**VirtualBox kernel: [ 1274.037659] audit: type=1400 audit(1500117397.021:8): lsm=SMACK fn=smack_inode_getattr action=denied subject="_" object="keys" requested=r pid=2574 comm="pool" path="/etc/keys" dev="sda1" ino=3932692**

It's strange that I ran openssl with execute "secure" as subject but I get in audit as "floor(_)". Can anyone identify the mistake?

Greets,
Satya

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons why this fail.

1. Write to /etc/keys/key is attempted by bash, not by openssl

   Your command "openssl rand 32 >/etc/keys/key" instructs the shell to open /etc/keys/key file for writing, execute openssl command and redirect stdout from openssl to the opened /etc/keys/key. Your shell is running with the floor ("_") Smack label, so it's unable to open the file.
   If you intend openssl to write to /etc/keys/key, try this instead:

   **openssl rand 32 -out /etc/keys/key**
2. You need to enable execute access from "secure" to "keys"

   This is because there will be two accesses from "secure" subject to "keys" object. When openssl opens /etc/keys/key file for writing, it must also have access to /etc/ and /etc/keys/ directories. Access to directories is realized by Smack "x" permission. Therefore you need to extend rule "secure keys rw" to "secure keys rwx".

Comment: It worked. Thanks Rafl. I had to make sure ~/.rnd also has the same label as openssl.